# Odd-order groups with homocyclic sylow subgroups

Tags: finite-groups

We say that $G$ is a homocyclic group, if it is direct product of isomorphic cyclic groups.
Is there any classification of finite odd-order groups which all their Sylow subgroups are homocyclic?

Comment: I am not aware of one. Do you think they would be substantially different from odd order groups with all Sylow subgroups Abelian?

Comment: I don't know, but a calssification of odd order groups with all Sylow subgroups abelian is also good.